# manipulation on array with objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how i make this manipulation on my array, Would appreciate help

my array looks like:

```
let array = [
    {name:"Don", hobby1:"fishing", hobby2:"cooking", hobby3:"acting"},
    {name:"John", hobby1:"fishing", hobby2:"cooking", hobby3:"acting"},
    {name:"Jorge", hobby1:"fishing", hobby2:"cooking", hobby3:"acting"},
    {name:"Maliy", hobby1:"fishing", hobby2:"cooking", hobby3:"acting"}
]
```

And what I'm trying to do is to catch all the hobbies and put them in array inside the objects.

Like this:

```
   [
      {name:"Don", hobbies:["fishing","cooking","acting"]},
      {name:"John", hobbies:["fishing","cooking","acting"]},
      {name:"Jorge", hobbies:["fishing","cooking","acting"]},
      {name:"Maliy", hobbies:["fishing","cooking","acting"]},
   ]
```

Comment: So what is your current approach?

Comment: @dh4ze  It's more useful to the OP if he explains what he has tried, even if it failed, and then get help.  In the long run the OP will learn & develop much faster than using SO as a code writing service.

Comment: @Keith I understand but downvoting isn't helpful, too. A lot of questions on SOF are already in such format like these, and they have hunders of upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do what you are attempting to do:

```
array.map(e => ({
    name: e.name,
    hobby: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e).filter(k => k.startsWith('hobby')).map(k => e[k]),
}));
```

#### Explanation

```
// Input
> e = {name:"Don", hobby1:"fishing", hobby2:"cooking", hobby3:"acting"}

// Get all property names
> keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)
["name", "hobby1", "hobby2", "hobby3"]

// Keep only names that starts with 'hobby'
> keys = keys.filter(k => k.startsWith('hobby'))
["hobby1", "hobby2", "hobby3"]

// Map names to values
> keys.map(k => e[k]);
["fishing", "cooking", "acting"]
```